# SQL group users if they belong to one or several groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to count unique users that have exclusively Bucket A, exclusively Bucket B or both Bucket A and B. My table looks like that:

```
DateKey User Bucket
05-18   1   A
05-18   1   B
05-18   2   B
05-18   3   A
05-18   4   A
05-18   4   A
04-18   1   A
04-18   1   B
04-18   2   B
04-18   3   A
04-18   4   A
04-18   4   A
```

Get the structure here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45a36/1

And the result I want would be something like that:

```
DateKey Bucket UniqueUsers
05-18   A      2
        B      1
        A+B    1
04-18   A      2
        B      1
        A+B    1
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45a36/11

```
select DateKey
, max(case 
    when IsA = 1 and IsB = 0 then 'A' 
    when IsA = 0 and IsB = 1 then 'B' 
    when IsA = 1 and IsB = 1 then 'A+B' 
  end) Bucket 
, count(distinct [User]) UniqueUsers
from
(
  select DateKey
  , [User]
  , max(case when bucket = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) IsA
  , max(case when bucket = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) IsB
  from table1
  group by DateKey, [User]
) x
group by DateKey, IsA, IsB
order by DateKey, IsA + (IsB * 2)
```

Our subquery squashes each user/datekey down to 1 row with columns to say if there's a value for A and/or B.

We can then group these rows by `DateKey`, `IsA` and `IsB` to squash them into 1 row for each `DateKey` value and each combination of `IsA` and `IsB` (`1, 0`, `0, 1`, and `1, 1`; `0, 0` does not exist since that would require there to be no row in `table1`, so that result wouldn't be produced).

Finally we count the number of distinct users within each of these groups.

NB: The order by is just to get `A, B, A+B`... i.e. I've made it so that `(1,0)` = 1, `(0,1)` = 2, `(1,1)` = 3.

Comment: No worries, thank-you for a really clear and well formatted question, with SQL Fiddle; you really made my life easy; thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two buckets, I would do:

```
select DateKey, buckets, count(*) as  UniqueUsers
from (select DateKey, [User],
             (case when min(bucket) <> max(bucket)
                   then min(bucket) + '+' + max(bucket)
                   else min(bucket)
              end) as buckets
      from table1 t
      group by DateKey, [User]
     ) t
group by DateKey, buckets
order by DateKey, len(buckets), buckets;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45a36/15) is the SQL Fiddle.